# Joining 2 Models in Django

Tags: django, model-view-controller

Im trying to join 2 tables in a django view. I currently have two models

The join could be done on *ticker* and *date*. As both models have them.

```
SSALiReport.objects.all()
NELiReport.objects.all()
```

***NELI*** looks like this

```
        {
            "clout": 40000,
            "date": "2018-05-15",
            "sentiment": 500,
            "ticker": "AAPL"
        },
```

***SALI*** looks like this

```
    {
        "date": "2018-05-15",
        "market": "NYSE",
        "prediction": 0.6,
        "price": 300,
        "ticker": "AAPL"
    },
```

I want a third view that looks like this, lets call it ***FullReport***

```
    {
        "date": "2018-05-15",
        "market": "NYSE",
        "prediction": 0.6,
        "price": 300,
        "ticker": "AAPL",
        "clout": 40000,
        "sentiment": 500

    },
```

How do I pull this in a view? Also note I want to be able to many rows by date. So I'll need to join the two tables

for reference see the model

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField
from django.db import models
import datetime

# Create your models here.

class SSALiReport(models.Model):

    date = models.DateField()
    ticker = models.CharField(max_length=10,default='NA')
    market = models.CharField(max_length=250,default='NA')

    price = models.FloatField()
    prediction = models.FloatField()


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.date) + " - " + str(self.ticker)


class NELiReport(models.Model):

    date = models.DateField()
    ticker = models.CharField(max_length=10,default='NA')
    sentiment = models.FloatField(default='0.0')
    clout = models.FloatField(default='0.0')
    top_news = JSONField(default='{}')


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.date) + " - " + str(self.ticker)
```

this SQL script works

```
SELECT *
FROM api_neli_report, api_ssali_report
WHERE api_neli_report.ticker = api_ssali_report.ticker
AND api_neli_report.date =  api_ssali_report.date
```

what is the django equivalent?

Comment: post your models, that will be easier for us to understand

Comment: Can you give more information on both models? In particular, what field do you use to link instances? It seems the field `ticker` can be used to join instances, but it's hard to tell without more info

Comment: Just added the model

Comment: No relation between models. Based on what parameter you merge it ?

Comment: Yes there is, ticker and date

Comment: what if it has more objects with same date ? I think It should have a `foreign key` or `one-to-one` relation.

Comment: Hey Anjaneyulu, I have tried a new object with one-to-one but it has created a third table. I want to just pull the data as its already there.  It's starting to look like this may be the only option.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do a raw query, if you don't want to change your models.
See the documentation: [Performing raw SQL queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/sql/)

Comment: I think your right. I'll give it a go today and update you

Comment: It's working, but I need the data type as a querySet not a RawQuerySet is there a way to cast/convert it?